# ionic2 accordion list render issue

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am implementing an accordion list in my Ionic2 application. My component:

```
export class ContactPage {

    public days : any[];
    public shownGroup;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

        this.days= [

        { "id": 0,
        "name": 'Ihr heutiger Trainingsplan',
        "exercises":[

        {"id":1,"name":'Best Stretch', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"},
        {"id":8,"name":'Farben', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},

        {"id":2,"name":'Butterfly reverse', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"},
        {"id":9,"name":'Punktgenaue Reaktion', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},

        {"id":3,"name":'SquatRow', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"},
        {"id":10,"name":'Loslassen', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},

        // {"id":13,"name":'Wortpaare 1', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},
        {"id":4,"name":'Plank', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"},
        {"id":11,"name":'Wortpaare', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"}, //word-pair 1 : just show words

        {"id":5,"name":'Push Up', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"},
        {"id":12,"name":'Wortschatz', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},

        // {"id":14,"name":'Wortschatz 1', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"}, // word-pair 2 : actual game
        {"id":6,"name":'Side Plank', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"}, 
        {"id":7,"name":'Squat', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"}


        ]
    }

    ];

    this.days.forEach((value1, key) =>{


        value1.exercises.forEach((value2) =>{

        })
    });
}

    toggleGroup(group: any){

        if(this.isGroupShown(group)){
            this.shownGroup=null
        }
        else
        {
            this.shownGroup=group

        }
    }

    isGroupShown(group){

        return this.shownGroup==group;

    }
}
```

My template:

```
<ion-list>

    <div *ngFor="let day of days"><br>
      <div class="item item-icon-left" (click)="toggleGroup(day)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(day)}">
         <ion-icon *ngIf="!isGroupShown(day)" name="add"></ion-icon>
         <ion-icon *ngIf="isGroupShown(day)" name="remove"></ion-icon>
        {{day.name}}

      </div>

       <a class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" href="#"[hidden]="!isGroupShown(day)" *ngFor="let exercise of day.exercises">
          {{exercise.name}}      
        </a>

  </div>
</ion-list>
```

And css:

```
page-contact {

    .list .item.item-accordion {
        line-height: 50px;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        transition: 0.09s all linear;
    }
    .list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide {
        line-height: 0px;
    }
    .list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-add,
    .list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-remove {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to get rid of anchor tag (the code was originally from angular1 which I needed for navigation) and replace it with button (to implement navigation, as an alternative to anchor). When I replace my template to:

```
  <ion-list>

    <div *ngFor="let day of days"><br>
      <div class="item item-icon-left" (click)="toggleGroup(day)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(day)}">
         <ion-icon *ngIf="!isGroupShown(day)" name="add"></ion-icon>
         <ion-icon *ngIf="isGroupShown(day)" name="remove"></ion-icon>
        {{day.name}}

      </div>

       <button ion-button clear class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" [hidden]="!isGroupShown(day)" *ngFor="let exercise of day.exercises">
          {{exercise.name}}      
        </button>

  </div>
</ion-list>
```

[image]

What I need to change here to render it as a proper accordion list like in the first pic (also the horizontal line bellow each list element is missing)?

Answer (score 0):

`ion-item` was missing in my button tag:

```
<button ion-item class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" [hidden]="!isGroupShown(day)" *ngFor="let exercise of day.exercises">
          {{exercise.name}}      
        </button>
```